# How to accept microtransactions with a desktop application?

Tags: microtransactions

I want to implement microtransactions into a desktop application I'm working on, but the microtransaction services I know of are all targeted primarilly towards Flash or smartphones. Are there any that explictly support desktop applications?

Comment: This isn't related to SDL. Or C really, the main point is a microtransactions service that is accessible from a desktop application. Nail down some requirements and write down services you've looked at but didn't work for you (ie: Google Wallet seems to only support Flash and Javascript, Mochi Coins are flash-only, Facebook Credits requires a Facebook account, etc.).

Comment: You're right. I've edited the question to better reflect that.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to make those purchases outside of the game. E.g. have the customers buy those on your homepage, you can make the game open the web browser when they click on a certain button or something. Other option would be to integrate a web browser into your game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not integrate [Google Checkout](https://google-developers.appspot.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API)? It's XML based and posts data using HTTPS, which, if your going for cross-compatibility, would work in Android too. :)